# On a variant of Farkas Lemma

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

The version on Mordecai Avriel’s book *Nonlinear Programming* is:

> Let A be a given $m\times n$ real matrix and $b$ a given n vector. The inequality  $b^Ty≥ 0$ holds for all vectors $y$ satisfying $Ay ≥ 0$ if and only if there exists an m vector $\rho ≥ 0$ such that $A^T\rho=b$.

It seems that a more wildly accepted version is this:

> Let A be an $m \times n$ matrix and $b$ an $m$-dimensional vector. Then, exactly one of the following two statements is true:
>
> 1. There exists an $x \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $Ax = b$ and $x \ge 0$.
> 2. There exists a $y \in \Bbb R^m$ such that $A^Ty \ge 0$ and $b^Ty < 0$.

I can’t understand how these two versions imply each other. Besides, the explanation beneath seems questionable:

> An illustration of the Farkas lemma is given in Figure 3.2 for a 3 ×2 matrix A. The vectors A1, A2, A3 are the row vectors of the matrix A. Consider the set Y consisting of all vectors y that make an acute angle with every row vector of A. The Farkas lemma then states that b makes an acute angle with every y ∈ Y if and only if b can be expressed as a nonnegative linear combination of the row vectors of A. In Figure 3.2, b1 is a vector that satisfies these conditions, whereas b2 is a vector that does not.

[image: EC02376E-4B3C-4042-AB06-D14E0493BF11]

In my opinion, the shadowed region is exactly “consisting all vectors y that make an acute angle with every row vector of A”, however, it is not all vectors that “can be expressed as a nonnegative linear combination of the row vectors of A”. For example, $A_1=A_1+0A_2+0A_3$ can be expressed as a nonnegative linear combination of the row vectors of A, but $A_1$ makes an obtuse angle with $A_3$.

My questions are:

1. Is this variant of Farkas Lemma, and its illustration correct? And if so,
2. How does it relate to the other version of Farkas Lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two versions of Farkas’ lemma you give are in fact equivalent—this is just because the statements “exactly one of A or B holds” and “A holds if and only if B does not” are logically equivalent.

As for the illustration, the condition in question is whether $b$ makes an acute angle with all members of $Y$, not whether $b$ is *in* $Y$. Indeed, by definition, $A_1$ makes an acute angle with all vectors which make an acute angle with each $A_i$ ($1\le i \le 3$).